# Inconsistent message while upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10 and installer stuck

Tags: upgrade

The installer displays "Upgrading Ubuntu to version 20.04" whereas 20.04 is already installed and I asked for 20.10.

I hope this is harmless.

The installer has been stuck for about 12 hours at stage "Installing the upgrade" on "setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file".

How to get out of this without doing wrong?

After restarting, it is 20.04. Retrying distribution upgrade, the installer only allows a partial install, does not display version number, and is stuck again on "setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file".

Yesterday I have installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04 without problem.  Could the installer be disturbed by Ubuntu Studio?

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean my 20.04, I have tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Indeed I have

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-sERPT9/0950-ubuntustudio-menu_0.49_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I removed ubuntustudio-dektop and ubuntustudio-menu. Now `sudo apt upgrade` exits nicely.

Rebooting I see 20.10.